# Menu — How to add "current-menu-grand-ancestor" css class

Tags: php, functions, menus

Any tips in order to :

Add the css class `current-menu-grand-ancestor` to an item with the class `current-menu-ancestor` that has a child with also the class `current-menu-ancestor` via functions.php ?

Thank you !

Johan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will help you filter a menu item and add a custom class conditionally. ( Untested )

```
function add_nav_class( $classes ) {

    if ( class_exists( 'current-menu-ancestor' ) || $item->title == 'blog' )  {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-grand-ancestor';
    }

    return $classes;

}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_nav_class', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you Sam, I got this so far, but i need to test if any of the children has also the class 'current-menu-ancestor', and that i still haven't found.

Comment: the function you hook to `nav_menu_css_class` can take up to 4 args: `$classes, $item, $args, $depth`, see [nav_menu_css_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/).  `$item` is the "current" post.  With that you could use [get_children()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_children/) to decide whether to add your "current-menu-grand-ancestor" class.

Comment: can you explain _why_ you need this class?  Because if you're using it for the reason I suppose you are, you should be able to construct CSS/jQuery selectors to identify "grand ancestors" without actually having that class present.

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron Thanx for the input, I'll have a look.  Yes I'm using jQuery as a hack right now, but i find it not clean, as a small delay occures on the front.